# What is the "ammo" packaging method when ordering through hole parts?

Tags: component-selection

I'm familiar with bulk, tape and reel, cut tape, and tube, but what is "AMMO?"

Source: [Fairchild 2N3904 datasheet, page 2](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MM/MMBT3904.pdf)

Comment: Now I picture engineers with bandoleers of caps and resistors around their torso, soldering irons in their holster(s).

Comment: @DavidKessner "Now I have a soldering gun. HO-HO-HO."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After some additional searching, found this article "[Packaging of Electronic Components](http://thinkcompetitive.blogspot.com/2011/04/packaging-of-electronic-components.html)"

> "Ammo pack is similar to cut tape.  The ammo pack is a continuous strip of cut tape to a predetermined quantity.  However, the cut strip is then placed into its own manufacturer box for safe keeping.  Please see below picture for your reference."

[image: Electronic Components Packaged in Ammo Pack]

Comment: Just in case people are unfamiliar with it - the "ammo" reference comes from [belt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belt_%28firearm%29) ammunition, which is used with chain-fed weaponry.

Comment: This answer explains it for axial components, like resistors in the picture, but does not help to answer the question of what "ammo pack" is for radial components. Mouser offers radial capacitors in both "ammo pack" and "reel, cut tape" packaging. What is "ammo pack" for a radial component, when both pins are parallel and point in the same direction?

Comment: @AnT I'm sure it's exactly the same as pictured except a thicker tape on just one side https://upload.ecvv.com/upload/UserImage/20140828/SuntanMultilayerMONORadialCeramicCapacitorsAmmoPackingTS17R_6b8f6a1f-54ea-458b-9efe-da6d9209114a.jpg the ammo pack is just a really long cut tape in a zigzag fashion.

Answer (score 3):

There is no fundamental difference between "ammo pack" and "reel tape" method: both  involve securing components on tape in exactly the same way. Radial components have both pins held by the same tape, while axial components use two tapes.

The difference between "ammo pack" and "reel" is simply how that tape with components is packaged afterwards: in case of "reel" the tape is wound on a reel, in case of "ammo pack" it is folded in zig-zag fashion inside a box.

Here's an illustration from a WIMA datasheet for radial capacitors

[image]

As you can see they also recognize "roll" packaging.

Answer (score 2):

Both leads of a two-terminal device like resistors or diodes are on tape. See [here](http://thinkcompetitive.blogspot.ca/2011/04/packaging-of-electronic-components.html) for an image.